# How to get Only the different columns from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with the same columns. That I need to compare and get only the columns with modifications.

ID is the primary key and its what can be use to compare table A and Table B.

Table A the Original table and Table B is new table that will have the same modified data.

```
Table A
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+
| ID | Name |  Color  | Country |   City    |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | Jim  | Red     | SP      | Barcelona |
|  2 | Hugh | Blue    | PT      | Lisbon    |
|  3 | Marc | Violtet | UK      | London    |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+


Table B
+----+--------+---------+---------+------------+
| ID |  Name  |  Color  | Country |    City    |
+----+--------+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 | Jim    | Blue    | SP      | Lisbon     |
|  2 | Roosie | Blue    | PT      | Lisbon     |
|  3 | Marc   | Violtet | UK      | Manchester |
+----+--------+---------+---------+------------+
```

How can i make a query that give me only the modified data

Example

```
ID 1  Old Color Red New color blue.
Id 1   Old City Barcelona New City Lisbon.
...
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `union all` to unpivot each table, join the results and filter on changed values:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.col,
    a.val old_value,
    b.val new_value
from (
    select 'name' col, id, name val from table_a
    union all select 'color', id, color from table_a
    union all select 'country', id, country from table_a
    union all select 'city', id, city from table_a
) a
inner join (
    select 'name' col, id, name val from table_b
    union all select 'color', id, color from table_b
    union all select 'country', id, country from table_b
    union all select 'city', id, city from table_b
) b
    on a.id = b.id and a.col = b.col and a.val <> b.val
order by a.id, a.col
```

I am not generating the text that describes the differences because I find that it is most convenient to understand and manipulate columns, but you can easily do it with string concatenations.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7235e9e48baa24a09b14312ac2e941bd)**:

```
ID | COL   | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE 
-: | :---- | :-------- | :---------
 1 | city  | Barcelona | Lisbon    
 1 | color | Red       | Blue      
 2 | name  | Hugh      | Roosie    
 3 | city  | London    | Manchester
```

Comment: works perfect...  What if i want to get a a line that exists in one table and not in the other, mantaining the same ideia of getting  Id Cold OLD_VALUE , NEW_VALUE ?  obv is its a line added all old_values will be null, but i want to get the new value information... can you help?

Comment: @UcanDoIt: do you want all records from `table_a` and possibly those coming from `table_b`? If so, you can change the `inner join` to a `left join` and the add an `on` condition: `on '(b.id is null) or (a.id = b.id and a.col = b.col and a.val <> b.val)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select a.id, case when a.color!=b.color then 'old color '||a.color||' new color '||b.color end as color_change, .... same for all columns you want
from tablea a join tableb b on (a.id=b.id)
where a.color!=b.color or a.city!=b.city ...
```

This will give you one line per id. If you want a line per (id, attribute), the best performing SQL depends on the size of the tables, as well as the delta (i.e. how many rows are different). You can try this:

```
with delta as (select a.id, a.color, a.name, a.city, ..., b.name as bname, b.color as bcolor, ...
from tablea a join tableb b on (a.id=b.id)
where a.color!=b.color or a.city!=b.city ...)
select id, 'Old Color '||color||' new color '||bcolor
from delta where color!=bcolor
union all
select id, 'Old City '||city||' new city '||bcity
from delta where city!=bcity
union all
 .....
```